# Db2: Fetch top row based on multiple where and order by condition

Tags: db2

I have multiple duplicate account information such as acc num, acct type, branch, updated timestamp. We don't have any primary key in this table. Now I need to fetch the all thesw account information  which was updated recently.

Query I tried:

```
  Select acc_num, 
  Acc_type,
  Branch,
  From acc1_table, acc2_table
  Where acc_num = acct_num
  Order by acc_num, acct_type,
  Timestamp Desc
  Fetch first row only:
```

If I query like this, it is fetching only 1st row of a table. But I need the recently updated records for each accounts.

Sample:

| Acct_num | Acct_type | Branch | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111. | A. | Bbb. | 2022-05-11 |
| 1111. | B. | Ccb. | 2022-02-01 |
| 1111. | C. | Abb. | 2023-02-21 |
| 2211. | A. | Bbb. | 2023-03-01 |
| 2211. | C. | Cbb. | 2023-01-01 |
| 3311. | B. | Abb. | 2021-02-01 |
| 3311. | A. | Bcb. | 2022-03-01 |
| 4411. | A. | Bbb. | 2022-02-01 |

Expected output

| Acct_num | Acct_type | Branch | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111. | C. | Abb. | 2023-02-21 |
| 2211. | A. | Bbb. | 2023-03-01 |
| 3311. | A. | Bcb. | 2022-03-01 |
| 4411. | A. | Bbb. | 2022-02-01 |

Please help me to write a query to fetch all the accounts details which were updated recently from the table which has duplicate account number

Comment: You need to GROUP BY the employee and for each one retrieve the record with the highest salary or timestamp (MAX)

Comment: @data_henrik, I tried below -->
Select Emp_no, 
  Emp_salary, max(timestamp)
  From Emp_table, cust_tablr
  Where emp_no = cust_no
  Group by Emp_no,..-----> it is throwing an sqlcode -122

Comment: Follow the advice in the guidance for SQL0122N. Look up how to write a GROUP BY statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [select two maximum values per person based on a column partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593754/select-two-maximum-values-per-person-based-on-a-column-partition)

Comment: @mustaccio, in my case, only the employee_id is similar, all other field is having different values. I need few fields for the employee having max timestamp

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?  Why are you joining to `cust_tabr` ?  Show some example data and the output you want to get.

Comment: @charles I just gave cust_tab as sample.. Basically I need to match an account number from 2 table and get the account details from table 1 which was updated recently

Comment: Table 1 has duplicate account numbers.. I need to fetch 4 columns from table A.. Apart from account numbers, all other data for that duplicated rows are different.

Comment: So I couldn't use, select col1, col2, col3, max(timestamp) from tab 1, tab 2 where acc_num = acct_num group by acc_num......

Comment: If I use only select acct num, max(timestamp) from tab 1, tab2 where acc_num = acct_num group by acc_num... The query is working fine.. But I need to fetch other columns as well.. Please help me to write a query for this

Comment: I edited my post with sample data and expected output. Please help me to write a query for this

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it is not clear which column is from which table so you might need to add some correlation names

```
SELECT a1.acc_num,  Acc_type,  Branch, timestamp
 FROM acc1_table a1
INNER JOIN acc2_table a2
   ON a1.acc_num = a2.acct_num
WHERE (a1.acc_num, timestamp) in (SELECT acc_num, max(timestamp) as timestamp
                                    FROM acc1_table
                                   GROUP BY acc_num)
ORDER BY acc_num, acct_type, Timestamp Desc
```

Comment: Yes thank you.. the query is working fine in test region but in production region, we have more number of data.. So the query is taking long time to execute and at last abending with -905 sqlcode

Comment: Well try explainng the access path and add indexes on acc_num columns. Provide more information if you need more detailed answers. Having no primary keys but applying  resource limits is kind of strange.